# Как отключить движок Razor в определённом месте файла?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

Нужно экранировать символы {{}} и @ в определённом месте файла и приказать движку Razor не реагировать на них.
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Вроде нашёл такой вариант. Если кто-то ещё знает- напишите пожалуйста.

```
@Html.Raw("My text{{My_Param1_1}}")
```

Comment: Какую строку Вы ожидаете в результате? `@Html.Raw("My text{{My_Param1_1}}")` или `My text{{My_Param1_1}})`?

Comment: @"Anton Komyshan" My text{{My_Param1_1}} -впринципи этот вариант работает